# Scala: How do I convert this flatMap/map into a for-comprehension?

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I am having trouble with understanding how to convert this into a for-comprehension. Could someone please explain how this can be done?

````
    (parseCommand(x)
      .flatMap { c =>
        calculate(c).map(r => renderResult(c, r))
      })
      .left
      .map(e => e.value)
      .merge
    ```
````

Comment: You can't, at least not the whole expression. Not sure what `left` returns, but you can't mix that inside the `for` and then you may add another `for` for the next `map` but the final `merge` would also be outside. Anyways, the code would just look worse. - Why you want to transform it into a `for`?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided enough information to answer your question.

- What type does `parseCommand()` return?
- What type does `calculate()` return?
- Why translate to a `for` comprehension? What's your goal?

Assuming that `parseCommand()` and `calculate()` return the same or compatible types, then the 1st `map()` and `flatMap()` can be translated like so:

```
(for {
       c <- parseCommand(x)
       r <- calculate(c)
     } yield renderResult(c, r)
).left
 .map(e => e.value)
 .merge
 ...
```

The 2nd `map()` can't be folded in to this `for` because there can be only one `map()` per `for` comprehension. You could, however, turn it into its own, nested, `for` comprehension, but remember that it makes no difference to the compiler, so the only real reason to use `for` is to enhance code readability, and nested `for`s seldom achieve that.

Answer (score -2):

I managed to convert it like this:

```
(for {
      c <- parseCommand(x)
      r <- calculate(c)
    } yield renderResult(c, r)).left.map(x => x.value).merge
  }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I offered in my answer 2 hours earlier.